# Tkinter keeps crashing: updating label in loop (StringVar())

Tags: python-3.x, loops, tkinter, crash, label

I am having a problem creating a label that updates itself. My Tkinter window crashes after I use a `while` loop. As far as I am concerned I don't create multiple label and stack them on top of eachother, what would cause the program to crash and not to update the label. What can I do better?
Thank you in advance!!

With loop:

```
def testfunction():
    
    while True :
        f = open("exchange.txt", "r")
        insert = f.read()
        f.close()

        if insert != var:
    
            var.set(insert)
        
      
root = Tk()
var = StringVar()
var.set("start")

root.geometry("1920x150+-10+-35")

frame_main = Frame(root, bg="black")
frame_main.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1, relx=0, rely=0)

label = Label(root,width=10,textvariable=var, font='Helvetica 14 bold',bg="black", fg="yellow")

label.place(relwidth=0.9, relheight=0.9, relx=0.05, rely=0.1)

root.after(200, testfunction)

root.mainloop()
```

**IMPORTANT EDIT:**
This all happends when I open it via this script.

```
# writes down:
subprocess.Popen("python -i tkinter_samentha_tricks.py")
while True:

    r = random.randint(1,6)
    f = open("exchange.txt", "w+")
    if r==1 or r==2:
    f.write("1 or 2")
    f.close
    print(r)
```

Comment: what do u try to mean by `if insert is not var:` try saying `if insert != var:`, if thats wt you meant. and whats is your intention here, what are you expecting to get

Comment: By "crash" do you literally mean the app crashes, or does it simply stop responding?

Comment: @BryanOakley app crashes

Comment: Do you get an error? Also, are you aware that `x =+ 1` means "set x to 1", not "increment x by 1"?

Comment: @BryanOakley nope, the app crashes. I think its becauuse he is opening the file again and again, instead i wrote the code to open the file and then loop over the lines and then check, it does not crash now. Dont know if thats what the OP wants

Comment: It doesn't crash for me, and I don't see anything that would make it crash.

Comment: @BryanOakley ‍♂️

Comment: @BryanOakley If I use a "while True" loop stopps responding after a few seconds, without updating the label for a single time.

Comment: @CoolCloud I've updated my question, Thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using while loop will block tkinter from updating the widgets, use `after()` instead:

```
def testfunction():
    try:
        with open("exchange.txt", "r") as f:
            insert = f.read()
            if insert != var.get():
                var.set(insert)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        #print('file not found')
        pass
    root.after(100, testfunction)
```

Comment: Thank You so much, I've been trying to do the same thing just with import a variable from the other script (it didn't work), what do you think: Is using a textfile approche a good solution compared to using classes ?